# How to compare a option according to its content in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following code I want to select the option tag using jquery and want to compare its content with "Not listed".

```
<select class="form-control" name="manual_appointment_practice" id="manual_appointment_practice">
    <option value="0">Select Practice</option>
    @foreach($overview['network_practices'] as $practice)
    <option value="{{ $practice['id'] }}">{{ $practice['name'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
    <option value="0">Not listed</option>
```

Comment: Do you want to get selected value?

Comment: What do you want compare exactly?

Comment: No I want to get the content of options according to their values @Vaidas

Comment: I want to compare the option values to the string "Not listed". @Jose Rojas

Comment: @Vaidas -No I want to get the content of options according to their values

Comment: What do you mean "according to their values"? You want to know what kind of text is in an option with some specific value?

Comment: Show us your jQuery code, let us see what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get text of the option selected you can do through:

```
$( "#manual_appointment_practice option:selected" ).text();
```

if you want to get the value:

```
$( "#myselect" ).val();
```

to get the text from the "Not listed" option try this:

```
$( "#manual_appointment_practice option[value='0']" ).text();
```